# How to send confirmation mail to new email address in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that can change current email address of a user. I want when user changes his current email address to a new email address to automatically sends confirmation mail to this new email address where user would confirm that email. How can that be done? Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

UserProfileController.php

```
public function changeEmailAddress(UpdateEmailRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->new_email != $request->repeat_email)
        return response()->json(['status' => 'Emails do not match.'], 404);

    if ($request->new_email == $request->user()->email)
        return response()->json(['status' => 'Email cannot be the same as old email'], 404);

    if(sizeof(User::where('email','=',$request->new_email)->get()) > 0)
        return response()->json(['status' => 'Email already exists'], 404);

    $request->user()->email = $request->new_email;
    $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
    $request->user()->save();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<section data-edit="email" class="editEmail">
    <form action="{{ route('user.update.email') }}" method="POST" class="flex">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="New Email Adress" name="new_email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Repeat Email Adress" name="repeat_email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="submit">BUTTON</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

web.php

```
Route::patch('/profile/change-email', 'UserProfileController@changeEmailAddress')- 
 >name('user.update.email');
```

UpdateEmailRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
    ];
 }
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

Answer (score 0):

To laravel  5.7+ implements MustVerifyEmail in your `App\Models\User` or `App\User`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

and in `app/routes/web.php`

Add such routes as email/verify and email/resend to the app:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

and simple in your method just call this:

```
$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

All you should have to do is call `event(new \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered($user));`

If that doesn't work, there may be a few things you need to set up first (see Longer Answer).

### Longer answer:

There are a few things you need in order to add backend support for user email verification.

First step is making sure your `User` model implements the proper methods:

```
// app/User.php:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {
    // this provides:
    //  ->markEmailAsVerified(),
    //  ->hasVerifiedEmail(): bool
    //  ->sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    use \Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

There's a nice built-in event you can then use to fire off an email to users once they register. You can trigger this manually or as part of a model listener (not discussed here). This needs to be registered in your event listeners first, though. See [Laravel's Event guide](https://laravel.com/docs/events) for more information.

```
// app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php:
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $listen = [
        // ...
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered' => [
            'Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification',
        ],
```

Once those two things are in place, triggering the verification email can be done anywhere in your application:

```
// fire off the Registered event, so that new users get a verification email
event(new \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered($user));
```

This will only work if the event listener is in place, and `User` has the right hierarchy.

The event handler (`SendEmailVerificationNotification`) checks if `$user` is a `MustVerifyEmail` that's not already verified, and if it is, it calls `$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification` which fires off an instance of `\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was unavailable. With this code above I get this error  Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
 "

Comment: "Authentication required" is not coming from Laravel. HTTP 530 isn't a standard response code, being used primarily by Pantheon to indicate a site is frozen. Are you sure Laravel can send emails?